# How to Call onActivityResult for Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-4.4-kitkat, galaxy, android-5.1.1-lollipop

First, the English writing skills are lacking.

1. Use Device: galaxy note2 (android 4.4.2)
2. Problems

   - A Activity -> Intent -> B Activity
   - B Activity -> Return Intent -> A Activity not Call onActivityResult
   - Come to debugging,
     The 'onPause' of A Activity and 'onResume' of A Activity  is run before B Activity switch.
   - So be 'onActivityResult' is first run is not getting the 'onActivityResult' behavior.
3. In normal operation, but it 'nexus 5(android 5.1.1)'

Comment: More than English, what is lacking is the code.

Comment: Can you add the most important part of your code plz?

Answer (score 1):

You should `setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)`.

[documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int))

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(A.this , B.class);
 setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```

In onActivityResult

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (resultCode == 0) 
    //do here anything
 }
```

[Read this Example](http://www.mybringback.com/android-sdk/12204/onactivityresult-android-tutorial/)

Comment: link has been broken